# Proof checking: subsequential convergence implies compactness

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I attempt to solve this problem:

> If $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and every sequence $\{p_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of points in $A$ has a subsequence converging to a point in $A$, then $A$ is compact.

An important theorem (Heine–Borel theorem) to support my proof:

> $A$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$, $A$ is compact.

I was thinking that since if $A$ is closed and bounded, $A$ would be compact so I am trying to prove that $A$ is closed and $A$ is bounded.

Here is my proof:

> $1)$ Suppose $A$ is not bounded, satisfying the condition. Since $A$ is unbounded, there exists a sequence $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ such that $|p_n|>n$. Its subsequence does not converge on $\Bbb R^n.$ It contradicts to the condition given by the problem so $A$ is bounded.
>
> $2)$ Suppose $A$ is not closed, there exists a limit point $x$ of $A$, $x \not \in A.$ Since $x$ is a limit point, $\forall n>0, \exists x_n \text{ s.t. } |x_n-x|<\frac{1}{n},x_n \in A, x_n \neq x$. Then $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of points. Since the subsequence of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ always converges to $x$. $x \in A$, which brings out an contradiction. So $A$ is closed.
>
> Since $A$ is closed and bounded, by Heine–Borel theorem, $A$ is compact.

I am not sure my proof is right or not? Because my proof is different from the proof given [by the link](http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eralston/131bh.1.02w/P6.pdf). If anything wrong, what is it? Is there any link between the proof given by the hyperlink and the one given by me?

Comment: Well your proof is correct.

Comment: @yanko Not Really, I felt something missing here. For example, how to guarentee that the subsequence always converges to x.

Comment: well, this is true, you just didn't prove that... notice that $|x_{n_k}-x|<1/{n_k}$

Comment: You can also show $A$ is closed as follows: Let  $S=(p_n)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence of points of $A.$  Then $S$ converges to some $p,$ and every sub-sequence of $S$ also converges to $p.$  So $p\in A.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with 1), why do you say $(p_n)_n$ has no  convergent subsequence? It *is* true but needs a small lemma: a convergent sequence is bounded, plus the fact that every subsequence of $(p_n)$ is also unbounded.

With 2: Let $x \in \overline{A}$. Then $x \in \overline{A}$ means there is a sequence $(a_n)_n$ from $A$ such that $a_n \to x$ (this holds in all metric spaces, and indeed it suffices to pick $a_n \in B(x,\frac{1}{n})$ for this).

So there is an $a \in A$ and a subsequence $a_{n_k} \to a$ by assumption on $A$.
But any subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit, so $a_{n_k} \to x$. As limits of (sub)sequences are unique: $x =a \in A$, so $A$ is closed.

No need to go with a contradiction.